# writing NSString type to a file

Tags: iphone, nsstring, char

I'm implementing the following function on `appdelegate`,
but I need to write `NSString` type instead of typical float values.
Since xcode doesn't allow an object to be in my desired position,
I used `char*` instead as follows, where as my data to be passed are of type `NSString`.
As expected, it doesn't work...
How could I manipulate it so that I could write `NSString` data type?
Should I make some conversion?
Please help me out..

```
- (void)addHallOfFamer:(char*)newHofer{
    [hofArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newHofer]];
    [hofArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSArray* paths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* hofArrayPath = [documentsDirectory
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hofers.plist"];
    [hofArray writeToFile:hofArrayPath atomically:YES];
}
```

(added)
following is how I'm calling the written NSStrings from another view, which doesn't reflect my updating.

```
MainAppDelegate* delegate;
delegate = (MainAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray *hofers = [[delegate.hofArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
hoferName1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[hofers objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, with the current `char *` argument, you need to use %s as your format directive, not %@.

Second, to use an `NSString *` as your argument, just add it to hofArray.

Comment: I edited so that NSString is directly added to hofarray. NSLog shows that it is successfully added to the delegate's hofarray, and then I write it to file... but then calling hofarray from another modal view shows that it is not updated... what could be wrong??

Comment: is there any way I could directly check the generated plist so that I can check the updated contents?

Comment: Since you are sorting the array after adding the item, are you certain it is still the last item in the array? Because the code you added is always looking for the last item in the array.

Comment: you were right! I should've just added items directly to hofArray

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to just save the array in NSUserDefaults.  Since it is an array of strings, saving and retrieving it that way should work fine and would be easier than dealing with the iOS filesystem.

---

Edit:
If you really want to save it in the filesystem, look into the [NSKeyedArchiver](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method `+ (BOOL)archiveRootObject:(id)rootObject toFile:(NSString *)path` and the [NSKeyedUnarchiver](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method `+ (id)unarchiveObjectWithFile:(NSString *)path`.

---

Edit 2:
As ondmike pointed out, you need to use `%s` rather than `%@` for your `-stringWithFormat:` method call to work properly.  Relevant documentation is [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)

---